# Rest api cakephp pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have been working on cakephp. I created an Api and configure the routes but I want to display pagination in the json result but i could't

Here is my code :

```
class DronesController extends AppController {


  public $paginate = [
      'page' => 1,
      'limit' => 5,
      'maxLimit' => 6,
      'fields' => [
          'id', 'user_id'
      ],
      'sortWhitelist' => [
          'id', 'user_id'
      ]
  ];

  public function initialize()
      {
          parent::initialize();
          $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
      }
  public function view($id)
  {
      $drone = $this->Drones->find()->where(['Drones.user_id' => $id], [
          'contain' => ['Accounts', 'Cards', 'Pilotlogs']
      ]);
      $this->set('drone', $this->paginate($drone));
      $this->set('_serialize', ['drone']);
  }
}
```

here the result that i got : https://i.stack.imgur.com/obMyn.jpg

I want it to be like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDgBw.jpg

Comment: How exactly do you want your result to look like? Please clarify that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination details you need here are available in [Pagination Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-jump-links) and not the Pagination component.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to modify these data in your view.

```
// View/Drones/json/view.ctp

$pagination['has_next_page'] =  $this->Paginator->hasNext();
$pagination['has_prev_page'] =  $this->Paginator->hasPrev();
$pagination['current_page']  =  (int)$this->Paginator->current();
.....
.....

echo json_encode(compact("drone", "pagination"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Actually I don't have a ctp because it's an Api so it should generate the json automatically

Comment: Yeah, you don't really need a ctp, unless you have to customize as per your requirement, as in this case. You need not create ctp files for other Api modules.

Comment: I see . But even when I created the ctp file nothing is changed

Comment: You could remove this line $this->set('_serialize', ['drone']); from controller and retry. Use pr() or something in the view to check if it's been executed. It's probably unable to execute the view code. You should also mention $components = array(...., 'Requesthandler');

Comment: Could you post how you solved it? I have exact same issue and I can't get pagination to show up in the json results.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CakePHP 3, you may retrieve the paging data generated by the Paginator Component in the request parameters.

In your `AppController.php`, put this before the serialize variables checking.

```
if ($this->request->param('paging') !== false &&
    in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
) {
    $this->set('paging', current($this->request->param('paging')));
}
```

The function will now look like this:

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    if ($this->request->param('paging') !== false &&
        in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
    ) {
        $this->set('paging', current($this->request->param('paging')));
    }
    if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
        in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
    ) {
        $this->set('_serialize', true);
    }
}
```

The `if` statement is to check whether if paging data exists.

```
$this->request->param('paging') // returns false if it does not exist
```

You may notice that `current()` part. I used this to strip off the model name.

Without the use of `current()` the result will be:

```
"paging": {
    "Posts": {
        "finder": "all",
        "page": 1,
        "current": 6,
        "count": 6,
        "perPage": 10,
        "prevPage": false,
        "nextPage": false,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "sort": null,
        "direction": false,
        "limit": null,
        "sortDefault": false,
        "directionDefault": false
    }
}
```

With the use of `current()` the result will be:

```
"paging": {
    "finder": "all",
    "page": 1,
    "current": 6,
    "count": 6,
    "perPage": 10,
    "prevPage": false,
    "nextPage": false,
    "pageCount": 1,
    "sort": null,
    "direction": false,
    "limit": null,
    "sortDefault": false,
    "directionDefault": false
}
```

CakePHP's `PaginatorHelper` uses this method to access the paging data.

Source / reference: [Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php#L110)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$this->request->param('paging')
```

Is Deprecated.

In CakePHP 3.7 is possible to return pagination object using the following:

```
current($this->request->getParam('paging'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp 4.0 as per  [migration changes](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-migration-guide.html#id1) ,we have to use

```
$paging = $this->request->getAttribute('paging');
```